# What are these OSX buttons called, and how to make/use them in Qt

Tags: macos, qt, widget

I have not done any work with Carbon/Cocoa, only Qt. I know Qt has excellent integration with various OS's, especially Mac in the last version (adding sheets, drawers, support for files attached to windows, and more), so I suspect it can do this, too.

Here's the picture: [alt text http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/4604/picture2pz.png](http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/4604/picture2pz.png)

If you can't see it, there are four buttons on a bar at the bottom of a pane on the left of the main window (plus, gear w/ down arrow, refresh, and a window-collapse button). At the right is a handle for resizing the pane. The whole bar has a gradient-type background on it, with the top half light grey, and the bottom half a darker grey.

Is it possible to do this in Qt? Is there a built-in style or widget, or would I have to override painting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to customize the buttons to get this look. But it's not difficult. While you could custom paint the buttons, [Qt stylesheets](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet.html) are probably all you need. They're modeled after CSS and they're *very* powerful.

The effect you're looking for could probably be achieved with only a couple of lines of Qt stylesheet code.

Did I mention this would achieve the same look on *all* the platforms (if you wished)? :)

[Here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton) are QPushButton stylesheet examples.